# How to replace the first occurrence of a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, search, replace

I want to replace just the first occurrence of a regular expression in a string. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 79):

[`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) has a `count` parameter that indicates how many substitutions to perform. You can just set that to 1:

```
>>> s = "foo foo foofoo foo"
>>> re.sub("foo", "bar", s, 1)
'bar foo foofoo foo'
>>> s = "baz baz foo baz foo baz"
>>> re.sub("foo", "bar", s, 1)
'baz baz bar baz foo baz'
```

Edit: And a version with a compiled SRE object:

```
>>> s = "baz baz foo baz foo baz"
>>> r = re.compile("foo")
>>> r.sub("bar", s, 1)
'baz baz bar baz foo baz'
```

Answer (score 17):

Specify the `count` argument in [`re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

> The optional argument count is the
>   maximum number of pattern occurrences
>   to be replaced; count must be a
>   non-negative integer. If omitted or
>   zero, all occurrences will be
>   replaced.