# Python - Replace text before first occurrence of string?

Tags: python, regex, replace, substitution, string-substitution

So if I have a string like:

```
plz_work = "text I want to get rid of HELLO want to keep this text HELLO want to keep this text"
```

I want to remove all the text before the first instance of `HELLO`, like the following:

```
"HELLO want to keep this text HELLO want to keep this text"
```

In this case, I used regex, and tried the following off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945784/how-to-remove-all-characters-before-a-specific-character-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951660/how-to-replace-the-first-occurrence-of-a-regular-expression-in-python):

```
 re.sub(r'.*HELLO','HELLO',plz_work,1)
```

But I get this:

```
'HELLO want to keep this text'
```

Why does this happen? I thought the last parameter signified [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and means that it would only perform 1 substitution... why is it going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: All correct except `.*`: [use `r'.*?HELLO'`](http://ideone.com/LVUnMB)

Comment: `*` is for greedy repetition.  It matches as much of the prior pattern as possible. 
 `*?` is non-greedy.  It matches as little as possible.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ahhhh I see so it matched `text I want to get rid of HELLO want to keep this text HELLO` as the first possible substitution, so it didn't matter that I set the count to 1?

Comment: @ocean800:  Exactly.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks! :)

Comment: Another option is to use non-greedy matching with a lookahead assertion: `re.sub(r'.*?(?=HELLO)', '', plz_work, 1)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I see.. thanks! Hmm I guess another question, I don't specifically need the `r'` flag, correct? Because there aren't any `\\` 's in my pattern?